# Which versions should be used for Spark cassandra connection using java Language?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to connect spark and cassandra database using Java language. For connecting spark and cassandra I'm using latest version of Spark-cassandra-Connector i.e 2.4.0. Currently I can connect spark and cassandra using connector. I am getting data in RDD format but I can not read data from that data structure. If I used row reader factory as third parameter of cassandraTable() I am getting

> ```
> > Wrong 3rd argument type. Found:
> > 'java.lang.Class<com.journaldev.sparkdemo.JohnnyDeppDetails>',
> > required:
> > 'com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.reader.RowReaderFactory<T>'
> ```

**Can any one tell me which version I should use or what is problem here?**

> CassandraTableScanJavaRDD pricesRDD2 =
>   CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable(keyspace,table,JohnnyDeppDetails.class);

**My pom.xml:**

```
    <!-- Import Spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-M2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the class instance, you need to create a `RowReaderFactory` using the `mapRowTo` function, like this (this is [from my example](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/spark/UUIDTest.java)):

```
CassandraJavaRDD<UUIDData> uuids = javaFunctions(spark.sparkContext())
      .cassandraTable("test", "utest", mapRowTo(UUIDData.class));
```

when you'll write back, you can convert class into corresponding factory via `mapToRow` function.